# Why might my Elseif Statement fail?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I believe my elseif is formatted correctly but it is failing. I have tried wrapping the elseif in quotes (second == equal statement), adding extra equal signs. Not sure what else I can do.

```
if (window.location.href.includes("?") && window.location.href.includes("year=") )
        {

        console.log("replace the 4 characters following the equal sign");
        }

        elseif (window.location.href.includes("?") && window.location.href.includes("year=") == "false") 
        {
        console.log("last condition");
        }
        else {
        console.log("end");
        }
```

Comment: Should be `else if` not `elseif`

Comment: Because there is no `elseif` keyword in JavaScript? Check your error console.

Comment: `== "false"` would never be truthy for a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript `elseif` does not exist. Change that by `else if`.

Something else you'll have to change is

```
window.location.href.includes("year=") == "false"
```

Since `includes` returns a boolean but I think you're aware of that and it was just a desperate try.

Comment: ugh, can't believe it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the current format of the second conditional inside your `else if`, try `!(window.location.href.includes("year="))`. The current syntax is a little funky.

Answer (score 0):

try **else if** instead of **elseif**, you've wro